# How do I move files in Android IDE

Tags: android, android-ide

I'm using [Android IDE](http://www.android-ide.com) to develop, and I need to move source files from one folder to another, but I can't seem to find a way to actually MOVE a file (even copy and delete in two steps would work).

Am I blind? This seems like a required feature of any IDE, and given how good Android IDE is, I find it shocking if this feature was overlooked.

**NOTE**: This question is **NOT** about **Android Studio**!

Comment: Did you ask on [the AIDE Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/android-ide)?

Comment: I tried that, no response there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The (essential) feature to move files around is missing from Android IDE.

Workaround:

You can manipulate the files in any explorer. Your project files are placed in `/sdcard/AppProjects/YourProject`.

You can count on the fact that such a feature will not be missing for long.

Answer (score 1):

I would download a file manager (I like [root browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree)) and switch between the two apps as a temporary work around. That app is updated fairly often so I would also just shoot the developers a feature request. I am sure they would consider it essential as you do.

Answer (score 1):

> PREFACE: Use a file manager; this hack renames Java classes.

**Rename**, with the **relative path** as  the new name.
Let's say I wanted to move `file` from `/sdcard/A` to `/sdcard/B`. I'd long-press on `file`, chose rename, and type the new destination as `../B/file`.

This doesn't seem like deliberate feature, rather a side effect of blindly passing path strings to the underlying framework. Can't say I don't like it, although, I'd recommend using a proper file explorer app.

Comment: Have you tried this with success? This does not work for me - in my case, the class name (`public class ClassName`) was affected - surely, not what I was after.

Comment: I have, with success, but not with a Java file, and definitely not in a Java project though. I was already in AIDE's "freestyle" mode; I got there by simply declining to open/create a project when asked. I get the "rename class too" logic, because Java, though. My answer here is an abuse of AIDE's lack of input check, a hack. Which is why I suggest using a proper file manager.

Answer (score -1):

Right-mouse click on any element (folder, Class, or XML file) the click = 'cut'.

Right-mouse click on the folder where you would like the files to be moved to, and then select 'paste'.

This works the same as moving files in the file-system.

For the most part (depending on where you are moving to and from) you can just drag-and-drop your files to move them as well.

Comment: I'm on a Nexus tablet...how do you propose I "right-mouse" click?

Comment: Right...but that doesn't provide any option to move a file.  I have options to rename and delete during long press.  I've edited the question to further clarify I'm not using Android Studio, as I'm thinking people are assuming.  I'm using AndroidIDE (http://android-ide.com) which is an android app for use on tablets/phones.

Answer (score -1):

I often achieve this goal by simply drag and drop. And the IDE also takes care of all the refactoring stuff.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be drag and drop functionality in this IDE, if I long press I get a menu that gives me the option to rename or delete.

Comment: So do you have to use this kind of IDE on an mobile device?